# Testing a class without calling its initializer

Tags: python, testing, mocking, pytest

My goal is to test a class without calling its initializer (because the initializer has some side effects I want to prevent from happening for that test).

I can achieve this with the code in `test_1`, which works fine by itself. However it seems to somehow contaminate the init/new methods, because `test_2` fails when run right after `test_1` with:

`TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)`

When running each test individually, they both pass.

Any idea what is happening here and how I can fix this, i.e., how to properly reset the init/new methods after mocking and testing?

```py
import pytest


# The class to test:
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x


def test_1(mocker):
    """First test uses the class without triggering the initializer."""
    # Create object without triggering the initializer:
    a = A.__new__(A)
    # Store away the old methods:
    new_orig = A.__new__
    init_orig = A.__init__
    # Mock new/init methods:
    mocker.patch.object(A, "__new__", return_value=a)
    mocker.patch.object(A, "__init__", return_value=None)
    # Do the test:
    res = A()
    # ...
    # Restore new/init methods:
    A.__init__ = init_orig
    A.__new__ = new_orig


def test_2():
    """Second test uses the class as intended."""
    A(2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to avoid calling `__init__`, you can do it with the following code, without patching in `__new__`.

```
import pytest


# The class to test:
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x


def test_1(mocker):
    """First test uses the class without triggering the initializer."""
    mocker.patch.object(A, "__init__", return_value=None)
    # Do the test:
    res = A()
    with pytest.raises(AttributeError):
        print(res.x)
    # ...


def test_2():
    """Second test uses the class as intended."""
    a = A(2)
    assert(a.x == 2)
```

No need to store the new/init methods either.

Comment: Super! Thank you.

Comment: Your code is obviously much better and straightforward. Still, any idea why my variant didn't work?

Comment: @myke Frankly, I looked but couldn't understand! I'm curious so I may look more into it another day. It's very odd that the patching wasn't correctly reverted at the end of the function, and I assume we're dealing with a weird special case.

Comment: Thanks, @OctaveL, it turns out that I not only need to deactivate __init__ but also patch __new__ for my code. So I added a new question for that. Maybe you want to have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64737213/how-to-patch-the-new-method-of-a-class

Comment: @myke I'll take a look!