# How to patch the __new__ method of a class

Tags: python, testing, mocking, pytest

My goal is to patch a class' `__new__` method in order to control the exact object it creates in a test case. See the code below.

Each of the two tests `test_1` and `test_2` work as expected when run individually. When they are both run consecutively, however, `test_2` fails with:

`TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)`

Even if I store away the original `__new__` method pointer and restore it at the end of `test_1` (something that pytest takes care of anyway) it still produces the same result.

Any idea what is going on here? And what a working approach could be to achieve my goal?

```py
import pytest


# The class:
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x


def test_1(mocker):
    """First test patches the new method."""
    # Create object:
    a = A(x=3)
    # Make sure new method always returns this object:
    mocker.patch.object(A, "__new__", return_value=a)
    # Switch off the initializer (so it doesn't overwrite values in the pre-made object):
    mocker.patch.object(A, "__init__", return_value=None)
    # Do the test:
    res = A(x=1)
    assert res.x == 3


def test_2():
    """Second test uses the class as intended."""
    A(2)  # <- Fails (when run right after test_1)
```

## Update

Thanks to @OctaveL for pointing out that with this class definition, the tests work fine:

```py
class A(object):
    def __new__(cls, *_, **__):
        return super(A, cls).__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
```

Comment: For starters, your code works fine if you make `A` inherit from `object` and override `__new__` to make it return `super(A, cls).__new__(cls)`. I couldn't tell you why, though!

Comment: Also, why do you want to patch in `__new__`, exactly?

Comment: @OctaveL It was simply the most straightforward way to test a function that used a class which has some costly initializer method. However, I now revamped the code to be able to test differently which solves my immediate problem. It's still an interesting riddle, though.

Comment: I've spent a while looking and I'm drawing a blank so far. I just thought I'd let you know I was wrong to force `A` to inherit from `object`, as it does it by default it's not necessary (which I knew, but I thought it wouldn't work without it for obscure reasons. This isn't the case)